# Weighted line map from weighted point matrix using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two point layers, one of cities and one of stations. I also have a .csv matrix table with usage of those stations by people from those cities.

| **City** | **Station1** | **Station2** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **City1** | 5 | 12 |
| **City2** | 6 | 15 |

Now I want to create a map with weighted lines from each city to each station according to usage.

I'm using QGIS 3.22.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS, ArcGIS Pro and R you wish to ask about in this particular question. If it’s R then please include a code attempt.